# I can't define type to set an array of objects in a variable React.useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to set values that come from an .xlsx using the [SheetJS](https://sheetjs.com/) library. Below I'll present the codes and error, and soon after the forms I've tried.

Data output from **var dataToJson**:

```
(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {idSeller: 503, idSupplier: 20, financialGoal: 0, positivationGoal: 300, qtVenda: 0, …}
1: {idSeller: 3113, idSupplier: 9, financialGoal: 400000, positivationGoal: 6, qtVenda: 0, …}
2: {idSeller: 7303, idSupplier: 378, financialGoal: 390000, positivationGoal: 0, qtVenda: 0, …}
3: {idSeller: 3113, idSupplier: 964, financialGoal: 360000, positivationGoal: 0, qtVenda: 0, …}
4: {idSeller: 7116, idSupplier: 378, financialGoal: 310000, positivationGoal: 0, qtVenda: 0, …}
5: {idSeller: 7117, idSupplier: 378, financialGoal: 300000, positivationGoal: 0, qtVenda: 0, …}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Data inside objects:

```
5:
financialGoal: 300000
idSeller: 7117
idSupplier: 378
positivationGoal: 0
qtVenda: 0
__rowNum__: 6
__proto__: Object
```

Interface and code:

```
interface IXlsxData {
  financialGoal: number;
  idSeller: number;
  idSupplier: number;
  positivationGoal: number;
  qtVenda: number;
  // __rowNum__: number;
};
    
const Archive: React.FC = () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<IXlsxData>(null);
    
  const readExcel = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    
    reader.onload = (e) => {
    /* Parse data */
    let data = e.target.result;
    let readedData = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'buffer'});
    
    /* Get first ws (worksheet) */
    const wsname = readedData.SheetNames[0];
    const ws = readedData.Sheets[wsname];

    /* Convert array to json */
    const dataToJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
    setFiles(dataToJson); // ---- ERROR ----
    // setFiles([...files, dataToJson]);
  };
}
```

Error:

```
const dataToJson: unknown[]
Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IXlsxData[]>'.
  Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'IXlsxData[]'.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IXlsxData': financialGoal, idSeller, idSupplier, positivationGoal, qtVendats(2345)
```

I've already tried a few ways:

```
interface IXlsxData {
  [index: number]: { 
    financialGoal: number;
    idSeller: number;
    idSupplier: number;
    positivationGoal: number;
    qtVenda: number;
  };
}
```

and this:

```
interface IXlsxProps extends Array<IXlsxData> {};
const [files, setFiles] = useState<IXlsxProps>([]);
```

Comment: tip: use `file.arrayBuffer()` instead of using the FileReader

Comment: tip2: You don't need `{type: 'buffer'}` since it can auto detect if you pass in a typedArray

Comment: @Endless tip1: I didn't understand, how would the code be in this snippet?
tip2: when remove displays this error: **TypeError: input.replace is not a function**
_b64_decode [as decode]_ // as if it were needed for the XLSX library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition of `IXlsxData` is fine:

```ts
// you dont have to include ALL the existing fields here
// just the ones you're going to use later in the code
interface IXlsxData {
  financialGoal: number;
  idSeller: number;
  idSupplier: number;
  positivationGoal: number;
  qtVenda: number;
};
```

But if you're expecting an array of those values (as I can guess by the first log) you have to annotate `useState` like this:

```ts
const [files, setFiles] = useState<IXlsxData[]>([]);
```

Now to the real problem. The problem is `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws)` returns a value with type `unknown[]` but your `setFiles` is expecting a value with type `IXlsxData[]`. And now you have several options to ensure the compiler the result returned from `sheet_to_json` is of the desired type:

- type-safe way: [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

```ts
function isIXlsxData(data: unknown): data is IXlsxData {
  return (data != null)
      && (typeof data === 'object')
      && (typeof (data as IXlsxData).financialGoal === 'number')
      && (typeof (data as IXlsxData).idSeller === 'number')
      && (typeof (data as IXlsxData).idSupplier === 'number')
      && (typeof (data as IXlsxData).positivationGoal === 'number')
      && (typeof (data as IXlsxData).qtVenda === 'number');
}

function isArrayOfIXlsxData(data: unknown): data is IXlsxData[] {
  if (!Array.isArray(data)) return false;
  
  return data.every(isIXlsxData);
}

const dataToJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
if (isArrayOfIXlsxData(dataToJson)) {
  setFiles(dataToJson);
} else {
  // handle error
}
```

While type guard gives you a simple answer `yes` or `no` to the question: whether that `unknown[]` type is in fact your `IXlsxData[]`. Assertion function may give you more information on what exactly went wrong:

```ts
function assertIXlsxData(data: unknown): asserts data is IXlsxData {
  if (data == null) {
    throw new Error('IXlsxData assert failed: value is null');
  }
  if (typeof data !== 'object')
    throw new Error('IXlsxData assert failed: value is not an object');

  const errors: string[] = [];
  (['financialGoal', 
    'idSeller', 
    'idSupplier', 
    'positivationGoal', 
    'qtVenda',
  ] as const).forEach((prop) => {
      if (typeof (data as IXlsxData)[prop] !== 'number') {
        errors.push(`property ${prop} must be a number`);
      }
  })

  if (errors.length > 0) 
    throw new Error(`IXlsxData assert failed: ${errors.join(', ')}`)
}

function assertArrayOfIXlsxData(data: unknown): asserts data is IXlsxData[] {
  if (!Array.isArray(data)) 
    throw new Error('IXlsxData[] assert failed. Data is not an array');
  
  data.forEach(assertIXlsxData);
}

const dataToJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
try {
  assertArrayOfIXlsxData(dataToJson);
  setFiles(dataToJson);
} catch (ex) {
  // handle error
}
```

- I KNOW BETTER way: [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). You may take responsibility and if you're absolutely sure nothing else but `IXlsxData[]` ever comes from this `sheet_to_json(ws)` call just *force* the compiler to believe you:

```ts
const dataToJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws) as IXlsxData[];
setFiles(dataToJson);
```

Comment: for the current situation I used the last option. regarding error handling will be very useful ahead. thank you so much, you helped me more than i needed.